# Seeding the generator in Python's "faker" module not working as expected

Tags: python

It seems like the `seed` method of the [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) module is not working as I would expect. For example:

```
In [1]: import faker

In [2]: fake1 = faker.Faker()

In [3]: fake1.seed(0)

In [4]: fake2 = faker.Faker()

In [5]: fake2.seed(0)

In [6]: fake1.name()
Out[6]: u'Norma Fisher'

In [7]: fake2.name()
Out[7]: u'Jorge Sullivan'
```

Should the last two outputs not be the same name, considering that they have the same seed?

By comparison, the built-in [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module does behave in this way:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: rand1 = random.Random()

In [3]: rand1.seed(0)

In [4]: rand2 = random.Random()

In [5]: rand2.seed(0)

In [6]: rand1.random()
Out[6]: 0.8444218515250481

In [7]: rand2.random()
Out[7]: 0.8444218515250481
```

Why does `faker` not behave similarly?

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/03684c9659c423f689918c0054a923771f097c8f/faker/generator.py) shows that all Faker instances share a single RNG. Dunno whether that's deliberate. It looks wrong.

Comment: I started to have this issue when I upgraded the Faker from 0.8.13 to 2.0 version. I did not have this issue with 0.8.13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I make it, the `faker` seeds the global seed. This is fine, but it means that the second faker is pulling a global random number, so it is the same as if you were asking a second name to the first faker.

Comment: Indeed the `Generator` class' `seed` method simply calls `random.seed()`. Probably in order to work in the way I described, the `Generator` should have its own instance of `random.Random()` (through composition or inheritance) and seed that.

Comment: @KurtPeek I think that it would be trivial to modify the code to do so. It's github, I'm sure the authors would welcome the patch.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking to get the same result the way to do it is to seed the instance instead of modifying the global seed. Ie

```
In [2]: fake1 = faker.Faker()

In [3]: fake1.seed_instance(0)

In [4]: fake2 = faker.Faker()

In [5]: fake2.seed_instance(0)

In [6]: fake1.name()
Out[6]: u'Norma Fisher'

In [7]: fake2.name()
Out[7]: u'Norma Fisher'
```